# Use parallel arrays for storing application settings

Tags: c#, arrays, reference, settings

I'm trying to develop a system that uses parallel arrays that align with a text box value and the corresponding settings value.

```
TextBox[] boxes = new TextBox[] { box1, box2, box3, ... };
decimal[] values = new decimal[] { Settings.Default.Value1, 
    Settings.Default.Value2, Settings.Default.Value3, ... };
```

But I understand that arrays of primitive types are passed by value rather than by reference, so the actual Settings values don't get updated - just the values in the array.

Is there a way to make the `values` array a collection of references to the settings values themselves? It's just a lot easier than having to do something like:

```
Settings.Default.Value1 = decimal.Parse(box1.Text);
Settings.Default.Value2 = decimal.Parse(box2.Text);
Settings.Default.Value3 = decimal.Parse(box3.Text);
```

And then the other way around when you're loading the values back into the text boxes.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're doing here. But I think that given that the `Text` property is a string, and the settings defaults are decimals, I can't see any way to avoid explicitly converting between them when you update. References won't really help you here.

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? Sounds like bidirectional data binding.

Comment: No, all I want to do is make an array of decimals that will serve as references to the settings values.